# Sublime Text: Exclude selection with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to select only grouped parts with regular expression.

For following line in a log file

```
Mon Feb 09 20:07:43 PKT 2015: VerifyPdb.Rama: Status: FINISHEDPART | Message: {fep=98.0, op=3.0, ac=6.0, ap=9.0}
```

I made the following regex

```
(some regex for another line)|(rama\:).*(\{.*\})
```

To give me only this

```
Rama:{fep=98.0, op=3.0, ac=6.0, ap=9.0}
```

Nothing else should be selected. `.*` part in `(rama\:).*(\{.*\})` should be skipped from selection.

How can I do that? This is just for one of many values in the log file.

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/3 or https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/4 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj In sublime text it is only selecting `Rama:` on the lines having `\{.*\}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/4 is same as what I have been trying to do.

Comment: @AvinashRaj No. https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/4 selects everything between `Rama:` and `}` while https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/3 only selects the word `Rama:` from the lines which have those brackets.

Comment: this one https://regex101.com/r/pR8oF5/5 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj This is selecting the full line in Sublime Text. Sublime Text is the problem here, not the regexes I guess.

Comment: completely don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have a long log file and I want to extract some data from it with regex. When I type the regex in Sublime it selects all the text which matches it. Then I can copy the selected text and do whatever is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with [`(?i)rama:.*\K(\{[^\}]*\})`](https://regex101.com/r/dP2aS8/1). In Perl, regex can omit from the final match everything it found before with the help of `\K` option.

Here is a screenshot of Sublime Text 2 options:

[image]:

- Open file and press `CTRL+F`
- Type in the `Rama\:.+\K(\{[^\}]*\})` regex
- Make sure *Regular Expression* and *Highlight matches* are ON
- Click **Find all**
- Press CTRL+C

You should have all matches in the clipboard now.

[image]

Comment: This is not working in Sublime Text. And what are the square brackets `\[` for?

Comment: Please retry. I guess there was a problem when copy/paste, there are no `\[` inside the regex on the demo page. If `\K` is not working (and it must work acc. to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html, as Sublime Text regex flavor is Perl-based), I guess you will have to live with overhighlighting by either using `(?i)rama:.*(\{[^\}]*\})`, or just `(\{[^\}]*\})` that will capture all `{}`s. Or use another editor that supports .NET regex after to get only what you need with `(?i)(?<=rama:.*)\{[^\}]*\}`.

Comment: This regex is only capturing `{.*}` and not the word `rama:`. Which text editor can do that? I have a lot of data there in the log file that I want to extract painlessly.

Comment: Please have a look at an updated answer, I tried with Sublime Text 2 and got no issues.

Comment: Thank you for adding screenshots. I am probably not explaining the issue clearly. This regex only selected the part within brakets but not `Rama:`. I wanted something like `Rama:{fep=98.0, op=3.0, ac=6.0, ap=9.0}` selected.

Comment: There is no way to select discontinuous text. However, you can first get the texts inside `{}`, copy them to a new document, and then use then **Replace All** with `^` in **Find What** and `Rama:` in **Replace With**.

Comment: Should I delete this question and ask another about how to exclude some text from selection with regex?

Comment: Isn't the solution I described working for you? I obtained exactly what you want with 2 steps.

Comment: The problem is that I have a huge log file (in MBs) I simply want to use regex in sublime to extract/scrap data. Above is only one kind of `XXX: {values}` there are many others.
I did extracted all data using many regexes multiple times like a data entry job but I was expecting a simpler way.